# Console application with signals, threads and network, Qt or POCO

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, console, poco-libraries

I have to develop a console application interacting with a Qt Gui via IPC. I already have a good experience with the Qt framework, I am completely new to POCO. I also need a good SQLite wrapper.

What are the pros and cons of Qt vs Poco for my case ?

So far, I've listed:

Qt pros:

- very good documentation
- active community
- in my case, experience
- easy to use
- cross platform
- SQLite wrapper is nice
- Easy threading via signals and slots (no need of mutexes)

Qt cons:

- lack of integration with standard C++, everything works with Qt objects (QString, etc.)
- Meta object compiler (MOC)
- New developer must learn the Qt framework to code
- Stick to GCC 4.2.1 on Mac instead of the latest clang shipped from now on with Mac
- Must inherit from QObject to use signals, threads, etc.

Poco pros:

- easy to use ?
- faster for networking (Http in my case) ?
- No need of MOC
- builds with Clang seamlessly ?
- cross-platform
- easy threading ?

Poco cons:

- lack of documentation !
- small community
- ?

I hope Qt5 will be usable with clang, llvm on mac ?

I would very much appreciate your insight about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you considering boost? It has a nice IPC library.

Comment: boost is too low level for network and lacks of documentation imho.

Comment: If you need easy networking, then you can also look at http://www.zeromq.org/.

Comment: Tech evaluation questions like this are not valid for Stack Overflow. They're Gorilla vs. Shark-style questions.

Comment: Most of your cons listed for Qt are subjective.  EG, MOC isn't really an issue because it comes with the development environment and does magical things for you.  Many Qt developers probably don't even know it exists.  And the forced use of Qt classes (QString, etc) is bogus: you can use both, but the whole point of the Qt based classes is portability, which is what I assume you're shooting for in the first place when you want to create a C++ based command line app in the first place.